# how to copy the values present in ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am using ag-grid to bind values from a list, Is it possible to copy the value/data in the selected cell. I have tried to copy the value using ctrl+c but its not working is there any other way?

Please help me!

Answer (score 49):

There is a flag which will allow you to select text and then CTRL+C will work.

```
enableCellTextSelection=true
```

> This is not an enterprise config and can be at any time to enable cell
>   text selection.

Comment: This allows the cells to be copied, but not the headers

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: I get this error: 
compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'enableCellTextSelection' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.
1. If 'ag-grid-angular' is an Angular component and it has 'enableCellTextSelection' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ag-grid-angular' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

Comment: It seems that in the latest versions of AG grid this is an enterprise feature as well.

Answer (score 28):

You can do this using CSS below:

```
.ag-font-style {
  user-select: initial;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
}
```

This should work in any of the browsers viz IE, Chrome, Mozilla and may be Safari.

Comment: Had to change the selector to .ag-cell-not-inline-editing and it works

Answer (score 5):

Many users are asking for this feature:

https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/87

Anyway copy-paste features seems active only in enterprise version:

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-context-menu/index.php

Answer (score 2):

if you using angular, add this module in your module ModuleRegistry:

```
import { ClipboardModule } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/clipboard";
public modules: ModuleRegistry[] = [
   ClipboardModule
];
```

Comment: This is working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In the column definitions, set editable = true, for example:

```
const columns = [{
    headerName: "Name",
    field: 'name',
    width: 150,
    editable: true
}];
```

Double-clicking on a cell brings up an editor with the current text pre-selected, which can be copied out with Ctrl + C.

See: [Cell Editing Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/)

Comment: The downside of this being that now your users can edit cell content. My guess is most folks will want the ability to highlight and Ctrl+C the text without having to enable editing.

Comment: Enable "EDIT" cell content may cause side effects, this is not strongly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They have API methods to access the grids built-in clipboard. I have recently implemented this into my own grid.

In the onCellFocussed event I am saving the most recent focus column to a member variable:

```
onCellFocused(event: CellFocusedEvent) {
    this.lastFocusColumn = [event.column]
```

This needs to be wrapped in an array for the correct type. Then in your onCopy() handler (the function that gets called when CTRL+C is press or copy is selected from the context menu):

```
onCopy(){
   this.gridOptions.api.copySelectedRowsToClipboard( false, this.lastFocusColumn )
```

The first argument is whether or not you want headers to be copied, which in my case and I think yours, should be set to false.

Comment: i tried to copy entire ag grid table to clipboard ,but it is copied only headerof the table . my code is this.gridApi.copySelectedRowsToClipboard(this.props.data)   // this.props.data have array ag grid data

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work for

```
[enableCellTextSelection]="true"

<ag-grid-angular #agGrid [enableCellTextSelection]="true" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [rowData]="xdrData"></ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is dscribed in the official documentation.

> If you want to use a regular text selection as if the grid were a regular table, set enableCellTextSelection=true and ensureDomOrder=true in the gridOptions.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/selection-overview/

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by creating generic directive which copies the text in specified css selector on to clipboard upon clicking ctrl+c.

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33928558/457541) helped me at lot.

Here is my html:

```
<div copiable selector=".ag-cell-focus">
    <div  ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-bootstrap"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the directive code:

```
// keys: 17 - ctrl, 67 - c
angular.module('common').directive('copiable', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var ctrlDown = false;
        element.bind("keydown", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 17) {
                ctrlDown = true;
            } else if (event.which == 67 && ctrlDown == true) {
              var text = angular.element(attrs.selector).text();
              console.log("selected text for ctrl+c", text);
              if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.setData) {
                // IE specific code path to prevent textarea being shown while dialog is visible.
                return clipboardData.setData("Text", text); 

              } else if (document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported("copy")) {
                var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
                textarea.textContent = text;
                textarea.style.position = "fixed";  // Prevent scrolling to bottom of page in MS Edge.
                document.body.appendChild(textarea);
                textarea.select();
                try {
                    return document.execCommand("copy");  // Security exception may be thrown by some browsers.
                } catch (ex) {
                    console.warn("Copy to clipboard failed.", ex);
                    return false;
                } finally {
                    document.body.removeChild(textarea);
                   ctrlDown = false;
                }
              }     
            }
        });
    };
})
```

Note: I couldn't get `keyup` event to work so end up setting ctrlDown to false in `finally`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Vinod's CSS fix no longer works. This does:

```
.ag-theme-balham.ag-unselectable {
  -webkit-user-select: text !important;
  user-select: initial !important;
}
```

Comment: This does not work now either, tested on AG-Grid community 22.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ::ng-deep along with .ag-unselectable for community edition

```
::ng-deep .ag-unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: text;
   -webkit-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

for Enterprise edition you may check - [Clipboard](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/clipboard/)

Answer (score 0):

TS

```
gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    ...
    enableCellTextSelection: true,
};
```

HTML

```
<ag-grid-angular
...
[gridOptions]="gridOptions"
...></ag-grid-angular>
```