# Equivalent of ag-grid enterprise feature EnableRangeSelection (AngularJS) for cell copy

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using the free version of ag-grid with AngularJS , so I can't benefit from the EnableRangeSelection that comes with the enterprise version.

I mainly need this feature so that I can copy/paste multiple cells at once.

I would like to know if anyone has been able to have a range selection in the ag-grid free version by creating a custom function for that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to copy the values present in ag-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721419/how-to-copy-the-values-present-in-ag-grid)

Answer (score 1):

Ag-grid community version has a very basic cell(s) copy feature which allows you to select the text in each cell to copy to clipboard.

Using this gridOption - `enableCellTextSelection : true`

From the docs -

> **enableCellTextSelection**    Set to true to be able to select the text within cells. Note: When this is set to true, the clipboard service is
>   disabled. Default: false